# Can't create text and annotations outside Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The following Python code generates a figure using Matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook which is ideal in appearance for an application that I am working on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='lightgrey')

# Define some graph offsets
start_x = 18
start_y = 18
end_x = 24
end_y = 24

# Draw an arrow
ax.annotate('Target',
            xy = (18, 20),
            xytext = (14, 20),
            arrowprops = dict(facecolor ='red', shrink = 0.05, width = 2.5),
            ha = 'center')

# Set the limits of the plot
ax.set_xlim(start_x, end_x)
ax.set_ylim(start_y, end_y)

# Customize the grid
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') # Make the grid equal in both dimensions
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])                # Invert the y axis
ax.xaxis.tick_top()                             # Move the X-Axis to the top

# Title
middle_x = 14+(end_x-14)/2
plt.text(middle_x, 18, "THE TITLE" + '\nSubtitle\n 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n\n', color = 'k', fontsize = 18, ha = 'center')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The code generates the following figure.
[image]

Running the same code from a console application (with %matplotlib inline commented out) gives a less than desirable figure.
[image]

Maximizing that figure gives a little more detail.
[image]

Matplotlib has an 'add_axes' function which allows modifications to the canvas.
Modifying the code with the following
`ax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5])# [left, bottom, width, height]`
generated the following:
[image]

How can the code be modified so that generating the figure from a console application will look like the figure generated in the Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `show`ing the plot, you might be better off by saving it directly, as in

```
plt.savefig("thing.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

the parameter `bbox_inches` set to "tight" will give you the result you want.[image]

Comment: That is good except I need to show the figure in an app.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close by setting a figure size and constrained layout when you call `subplots`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6), facecolor='lightgrey', layout='constrained')

# Define some graph offsets
start_x = 18
start_y = 18
end_x = 24
end_y = 24

# Draw an arrow
ax.annotate('Target',
            xy = (18, 20),
            xytext = (14, 20),
            arrowprops = dict(facecolor ='red', shrink = 0.05, width = 2.5),
            ha = 'center')

# Set the limits of the plot
ax.set_xlim(start_x, end_x)
ax.set_ylim(start_y, end_y)

# Customize the grid
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') # Make the grid equal in both dimensions
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])                # Invert the y axis
ax.xaxis.tick_top()                             # Move the X-Axis to the top

# Title
middle_x = 14+(end_x-14)/2
plt.text(middle_x, 18, "THE TITLE" + '\nSubtitle\n 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n\n', color = 'k', fontsize = 18, ha = 'center')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Strangely, when I tried a square figure (e.g. `figsize=(7, 7)`) it did not work well.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about layout='constrained'.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT 4 gave me some ideas and one worked although it loses the odd numbers on the horizontal axis.

The key is to add: plt.tight_layout()

The following is the complete code:

```
# Define some graph offsets
start_x = 18
start_y = 18
end_x = 24
end_y = 24

# Set the limits of the plot
ax.set_xlim(start_x, end_x)
ax.set_ylim(start_y, end_y)

# Draw an arrow
ax.annotate('Target',
            xy = (18, 20),
            xytext = (14, 20),
            arrowprops = dict(facecolor ='red', shrink = 0.05, width = 2.5),
            ha = 'center')

# Customize the grid
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') # Make the grid equal in both dimensions
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])                # Invert the y axis
ax.xaxis.tick_top()                             # Move the X-Axis to the top

# Title
middle_x = 14+(end_x-14)/2
plt.text(middle_x, 18, "THE TITLE" + '\nSubtitle\n 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n\n', color = 'k', fontsize = 18, ha = 'center')

#ax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5])# [left, bottom, width, height]
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]